# How can I publish a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, publish

I have earlier used the funtion `publish` to publish plots and printouts as html in matlab. That have worked fine until now. The reason is that I have used a script that calls a function. However, that have now become cumbersome.

Former:

```
publish('myPlots.m');
```

Wants something like this (or similar):

```
publish(plotFun(inargs{:}));
```

What I would like to do is to use publish on this function only. I would also have only the plot and the printouts printed in the html (no code). Would this be possible and how? Else, are there any other known way of doing this?

It is of course possible write to a file (which is what I do now), but I want to try to avoid that since it seems kind of ugly.

/Patrik

Comment: I think `publish` only works with scripts, not functions.

Comment: @am304 I think that as well, but do you know if there are some other way of doing this, except coding everything by myself. That is clearly possible, but will be quite a project I think.

Comment: Can you not put the function call inside a script and publish that instead? There is an option or a setting to turn off the code in the generated HTML.

Comment: @am304 The problem is that I run the function from the terminal with different inputs. The solution that I use now can be seen as barely acceptable illuminated from its best side with its best clothes. What I do is actually writing the code to file and deleting the file afterwards. While this works it is certainly not a solution to be proud over. However, if this is the only way to solve it without having to write a custom publish function I guess it will have to do. Thank for your time anyway.

Comment: Personally, I would put all the function calls inside a script and publish that because I tend to go for the easiest solution :-)

Comment: @am304 Well that is fine unless the process is automatic :) But since the shell script I wrote does a lot of things I prefer to not force every user to 1) create a copy of the shell script, 2) read the shell script, 3) create a plot script, 4) edit the line where the script is published every time. I prefer to force the user to give a directory as input and let the shell script do the rest, which leads to my quite ugly solution, but I guess I can live with it since it works.